# Dynamic creation of html tags in polymer

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I have a list of items and I need dynamically create  tags with classes and text which depends on the item type. Currently I'm doing it in the following way:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{list}}" as="item">
  <span class$="[[_customClass(item)]]">
    [[_customText(item)]]
  </span>
</template>
```

This requires a definition of two functions, which basically have the same switch statement but return different values. Is there a more elegant way to create such spans with only one function call?

Comment: Can't you return an object, which holds the className and text from a single funcition?

Comment: As @Mr.7 said you can return an object, also, you could pass an extra argument to your function like this: `[[_custom(item, 'class')]]` `[[_custom(item, 'text')]]`

Comment: But I still need to call the function twice

Answer (score 0):

```
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[list]]">
    <span class$="[[item]]">
      [[_customText(item)]]
    </span>
  </template>
```

*items* defaults to item so you don't need the *as="item"*

Assuming the array is a string, you can just create css classes for each string value. If the item is an object, just go [[item.type]] and [[item.text]].

```
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[list]]">
    <span class$="[[item.type]]">
      [[item.text]]
    </span>
  </template>
```

When filling the items array, I would otherwise hash it into an array with objects, and set *.type* and *.text* as properties, and use what I wrote above. Then you only need to loop through the array once.